# JQGrid drop down selected option

Tags: jqgrid

I am having a non-inline edit jqGrid containing an editable drop down column.
I use string as the editoptions.value, e.g. 1:A;A:B.

There is one option having the value same as the key of another option.
Then when I want to edit the record, the selected option is mapped wrongly.  I found that this is due to the implementation in createEl function.  It check $.trim(sv[1]) === $.trim(vl) to set the selected option also.  May I know if there is anyone having the same problem?

I am using jqGrid 4.6.0. My code is as follows. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
        var mydata = [
            { id: '1', col: '1' },
            { id: '2', col: 'A' }
        ];

        var grid = jQuery("#grid");
        grid.jqGrid({
            data: mydata,
            datatype: 'local',
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'col', width: 100, editable: true, formatter: 'select',
                    edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: 'A:B;1:A' }
                }
            ],
            editurl: 'clientArray',
            height: '100%',
            viewrecords: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            pager: '#pager'
        }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Moreover it's better to post the JavaScript code wich some test data as to describe the problem only. I develop free jqGrid fork. It test the values of select first and then only in the value will be not found, then the text.

Comment: You can try free jqGrid by loading all files from CDN. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).